# Moving from Python 2 to 3: Must reinstall NLTK directory?

Tags: python, nltk, jupyter-notebook

When moving from Python 2 to 3 I know I have to reinstall NLTK for Python 3, but is it necessary to reinstall the massive directory as well?

I'm on Mac OS 10.12.5 and I've been working with Python 2.7 in Sublime3. I'm now making the move to Python 3, working sometimes in Sublime3 and other times in Jupyter Notebook. The thing is I installed NLTK for 2.7, but now that I'm moving to 3 I don't want to reinstall the enormous NLTK directory again for python 3. So I'm wondering if it's possible and easy to install NLTK for 3 but still use the whole parsers/corpora/etc. I already have.

Appreciate your help, and direction to a tutorial if this is possible!

Answer (score 2):

The NLTK data directory remains the same, so there's no need to reinstall the data all over-again.

But the code resides differently in the python's dist-package for Python2 and Python3.

So all you would need to do is to install `nltk` using `pip` and `pip3`:

```
pip install -U nltk
pip3 install -U nltk
```

But you only need to install the `nltk_data` directory only once, e.g. :

```
# Let's delete the existing nltk_data directory and start afresh:
alvas@ubi:~$ ls nltk_data/
chunkers  grammars  misc    sentiment  taggers
corpora   help      models  stemmers   tokenizers
alvas@ubi:~$ rm nltk_data/ 

# Install the NLTK code for pip3 (Python3) and pip (Python2)
alvas@ubi:~$ pip3 install -U nltk
Requirement already up-to-date: nltk in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages
Requirement already up-to-date: six in ./.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from nltk)

alvas@ubi:~$ pip2 install -U nltk
Requirement already up-to-date: nltk in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requirement already up-to-date: six in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from nltk)


# Now, download the NLTK directory in Python2

alvas@ubi:~$ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import nltk
>>> nltk.download('popular')
[nltk_data] Downloading collection u'popular'
[nltk_data]    | 
...
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package averaged_perceptron_tagger to
[nltk_data]    |     /home/alvas/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    |   Unzipping taggers/averaged_perceptron_tagger.zip.
[nltk_data]    | 
[nltk_data]  Done downloading collection popular
True

# Now in Python3, when we try to re-download the nltk_data directory
# We see that it doesn't re-download it =)

>>> import nltk
>>> nltk.download('popular')
[nltk_data] Downloading collection 'popular'
[nltk_data]    | 
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package cmudict to
[nltk_data]    |     /home/alvas/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    |   Package cmudict is already up-to-date!
...
[nltk_data]    |     /home/alvas/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    |   Package averaged_perceptron_tagger is already up-
[nltk_data]    |       to-date!
[nltk_data]    | 
[nltk_data]  Done downloading collection popular
True
```

---

**Can I just download a Python package for Python2 and make it work in Python3?**

Unfortunately, no. Installing a package/library in Python 2 is independent of Python 3's environment and vice versa. This applies not only to `nltk` but other libraries too.

Don't think of Python 3 as a later version of Python 2, think of them as two different languages ;P